# Asus Xtion camera calibration fails to start

Tags: calibration, openni, xtion, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to calibrate Asus Xtion following [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration) in openni_launch package. I'm getting following error:

```
$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.030 image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw camera:=/camera/rgb
Waiting for service /camera/rgb/set_camera_info ...
OK
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 68, in run
    self.function(m)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 133, in handle_monocular
    drawable = self.c.handle_msg(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 684, in handle_msg
    rgb = self.mkgray(msg)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/calibrator.py", line 233, in mkgray
    rgb = self.br.imgmsg_to_cv(msg, "bgr8")
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge/cv_bridge.py", line 106, in imgmsg_to_cv
    source_type = self.encoding_as_cvtype(img_msg.encoding)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge/cv_bridge.py", line 54, in encoding_as_cvtype
    return eval("cv.CV_%s" % encoding)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'CV_yuv422'
```

I'm running electric.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35428/asus-xtion-camera-calibration-fails-to-start./) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I had the same problem (using Fuerte), but I was able to calibrate my Asus Xtion by changing the launch call to:

rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 10x7 --square 0.025 image:=/camera/rgb/image_mono camera:=/camera/rgb --no-service-check

for the RGB camera, and:

rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 10x7 --square 0.025 image:=/camera/ir/image_raw camera:=/camera/ir --no-service-check

for the IR camera.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [Smot](https://answers.ros.org/users/2736/smot/) with karma: 61 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tbernhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1746/tbernhard/) on 2012-07-11**:
(Also on Fuerte) Worked for me, thanks!  I didn't need the --no-service-check, just the switch from image:=/camera/rgb/image_raw  to  /camera/rgb/image_mono